# In chrome my drag and drop Java applet doesn't get the drop events, does chrome not support that on Mac?

Tags: java, macos, drag-and-drop, google-chrome

I have an applet that accepts files via drag and drop from the OS which works in every browser but Chrome.  In chrome if you drag and drop a file from the OS chrome shows you the file in the browser, if you drop a .jpg for instance.  Does Chrome not support drag and drop for Java in OS X?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome for Mac uses a new Java plugin that isn't yet used by default in other browsers, and that plugin may not support drag and drop yet. Take a look at [this bug report](http://crbug.com/47404), starting with comment 2, for instructions on how to verify that this is a plugin bug, and if so how to report it to Apple.